# ta-lib есть для php?

Tags: php

Мне нужна библиотека сигналов и советников.
Нашел ta-lib - но она на питоне, есть ли аналогичная библиотека на языке PHP?

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что [вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Пожалуйста, переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы он не выглядел как "где найти библиотеку A?", а читался как "Какие есть аналоги библиотеки A для языка B?", без уточнения "где найти?". Иначе ваш вопрос очень скоро закроют, не сильно разбираясь в сути.